# Selecting an item from drop down menu when the menu uses input, not select

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to learn how to use Selenium with Python. I'm writing some code that will run a search on www.kijiji.ca. I'm able to select the search field and enter my query, but I can't figure out how to select the city from the list. In the Selenium documentation, I found where it says to use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('name'))
```

However, when I try to use the code, I get an error that says "Select only works on select elements, not on input"

I inspected the page again and it does seem like the drop down menu uses an input rather than a select. Can anyone help me figure out how to use Selenium to select the city here?

Comment: Did you try to click input and then click on required city?

Comment: @Jeff, are you still looking for a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select class if your element is a `<select>` tag. Refer [seleniumhq](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html), there it mentioned*Models a SELECT tag, providing helper methods to select and deselect options.*

Specific to you element, you can try below code as manually we simulate the action like click.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("SearchLocationPicker").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li a[title='Manitoba']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li a[title='Flin Flon']").click()
```

Working fine at my end. let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

The page uses custom select component which cannot be interacted with selenium `Select` class. The Select class can be used only for default [html select component](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select).

We have to automate it as we do in the manual steps,

1. Click the input test box
2. Wait for the dropdown list appears.
3. Click the value respective value appears in the the dropdown.

In your case, we can select the dropdown either with title attribute or by selecting display value of the anchor tag in the list.

```
 <a  title="Territories">Territories</a>
```

---

```
def select_by_title(value):
    # click the input component
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#SearchLocationPicker"]').send_keys(value) 

    # Wait for the value to appear in dropdown.
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#SearchLocationPicker~div>ul>li>a[title="'+value+'"')))

    # Click the element 
    element.click()
```

Or

```
def select_by_display_value(value):
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#SearchLocationPicker"]').send_keys(value) 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="SearchLocationPicker"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/a[text() = "'+value+'"]')))
    element.click()
```